# Checking if a certain value is in a subkey, then do something

Tags: c#, registry

Here i am trying to read from `CurrentUser\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0` folder. In there is a subkey called "UpgradeCheckScheduledTimestamp". If that has a value of true, I want to do something.

Seen many examples, but all are showing only if the value is empty or not. But I want to look for a specific value.

Here is what I have been fiddling around with so far

```
RegistryKey regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\12.0, UpgradeCheckScheduledTimestamp");

if (regKey != null)
{
    regKey.GetValue("UpgradeCheckScheduledTimestamp");
}

Console.WriteLine(regKey);
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. Just remove "UpgradeCheckScheduledTimestamp" from the first line of code.

Then you have to either assign the value inside the `if` statement to another variable, or just write to the console when you get the value. If the subkey is not found, it'll just write an empty line.

```
RegistryKey regKey
    = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\12.0");

if (regKey != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(regKey.GetValue("UpgradeCheckScheduledTimestamp"));
}
```

Comment: Oh ok, but it Returns nothing even though it has a value. Do i have to make my program elevated to gain Access to the registry?

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
object o = Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\...", "UpgradeCheckScheduledTimestamp", false);
if (o != null && Convert.ToBoolean(o))
    // Do Something
```

This should return an object containing the value or `false` if the value does not exist. Then it will try to convert the result to `bool` and do something if the converted result was `true`.

See [documentation of `Registry` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).